# Search files in a Linux remote machine with GUI tool

Tags: linux, windows, search, command, mobaxterm

I have a Linux machine and I'm accessing this Linux machine with MobaXterm and im using commands to create docker containers. I'm very new to Linux machine. When I'm creating docker files or containers with commands, it's saying with the same name it's already exists. Im not able to find where the file exists. Do we have any tool which helps you to connect the Linux machine like MobaXterm and search the all files in Linux machine like Agent Ransack. I can use commands to do all this but at this time it takes some time to learn them.